How to use dynamic layout for a Vue3 page
I have results page that can be accessed via a logged user as well as unauthenticated user. Both of these experiences have different layouts. How can I switch the layout for this results page depending on if the user is logged in or not.
My project is built using Vue3, with vuetify, pinia and vuerouter 4.
Current router.index is:
/**
 * router/index.ts
 *
 * Automatic routes for `./src/pages/*.vue`
 */

// Composables
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router/auto'
import { setupLayouts } from 'virtual:generated-layouts'
import { routes } from 'vue-router/auto-routes'
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/authStore'; 

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: setupLayouts(routes),
})

// Add a navigation guard to check authentication status
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  const authStore = useAuthStore();

  const isAuthenticated = authStore.user; 
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next('/authenticate'); // Redirect to login page if not authenticated
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

// Workaround for https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11804
router.onError((err, to) => {
  if (err?.message?.includes?.('Failed to fetch dynamically imported module')) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('vuetify:dynamic-reload')) {
      console.log('Reloading page to fix dynamic import error')
      localStorage.setItem('vuetify:dynamic-reload', 'true')
      location.assign(to.fullPath)
    } else {
      console.error('Dynamic import error, reloading page did not fix it', err)
    }
  } else {
    console.error(err)
  }
})

router.isReady().then(() => {
  localStorage.removeItem('vuetify:dynamic-reload')
})

export default router

I tried option 3 from this page:
https://itnext.io/3-ways-to-create-a-multiple-layouts-system-vue-3-b24c0736b7bb

You are using route middleware to check if the the user is authenticated or not, but if they can view the page either way why don‘t you put v-if in the template of the results page

That requires me to change the template of the component. I want to show a different page layout for this component.  (different navbar, different color theme)

you can use definePageMeta
definePageMeta({
  layout: "auth",  
});

In layouts folder, you can create files for auth users and unauthenticated users.
layouts > auth.vue // create other vue files based on your requirement

From results page you can use definePageMeta to show the different layouts based on authentication.

Hi, it looks like this solution needs nuxt. I am not using this currently in project but I will try it out if there are no other options.
Thanks!
